# Python: Find a Sentence between some website-tags using regex

Tags: python, html, regex, tags, urllib2

I want to find a sentence between the `...class="question-hyperlink">` tags.
With this code:

```
import urllib2
import re

response = urllib2.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python')
html = response.read(20000)

a = re.search('question-hyperlink', html)
print html[a.end()+3:a.end()+100]
```

I get:

```
DF5 for Python: high level vs low level interfaces. h5py</a></h3>        <div class="excerpt">
```

How can I stop at the next `<` ?
And how do I find the next sentence?
I want to do it with regex.

**EDIT**
To the downvoters:
I want to do it like he does:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1736801#1736801)

Comment: Have you considered using a HTML parsing library like BeautifulSoup, instead of regular expressions?

Comment: I don't like BeautifulSoup. :/

Comment: maybe http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/ then

Comment: For now I want to do it with regex, because I want to learn regex.

Comment: I'm sure everyone is sick of this link by now, but it's still apt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @ShawnChin: I think SO should automatically bring up that post whenever it detect the tags ((html|xml|xhtml)&regex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *must* do it with regular expressions, try something like this:

```
a = re.finditer('<a.+?question-hyperlink">(.+?)</a>', html)
for m in a: 
    print m.group(1)
```

Just for the reference, this code does the same, but in a far more robust way:

```
doc = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in doc.findAll('a', 'question-hyperlink'):
    print a.text
```